# How can I use ngModelChange insted of change

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using change to send the input data like this:

```
<input value="1" #options (change)="onSelected(options.value)" min="1" max="30" type="number" class="form-control select-input"  style="width:100%"/>
```

but I want to use ngModelChange insted when I do it the the default value don't show :

```
<input value="1" name="1" ngModel (ngModelChange)="onSelected($event)"  min="1" max="30" type="number" class="form-control select-input"  style="width:100%" />
```

[image: like this]

am I using it wrong ?

[this is](https://github.com/TaidaSa/MyStore) the full code it's in app/components/product-list/product-list.component.html
in Line 14

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need to bind to your backing property `selectedOption`. You only wrote `ngModel` which by itself it doesn't do much. But if you write `[(ngModel)]="selectedOption"` then it will have the default value that you set inside the `.ts` file. Moreover, you don't even need the `ngModelChange` and the `onSelected` handler only to set the value for the `selectedOption`. This is done automatically for you by the `ngModel` directive.

Comment: it's working but it changes every input in the page how cane I make change only the selected input?

Comment: Put the `selectedOption` inside the `productData` object, so that you have this available for every individual product.